# If $\sum a^2_n$ converges so does $\sum \frac{a_n}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $\sum a^2_n$ converges so does $\sum \frac{a_n}{n}$

I'm trying to prove/ disprove this statement. But I couldn't end up with anything yet. Any help?

Comment: (in particular, through the fact that $\sum_{n\in\Bbb N} \frac{\lvert a_n\rvert}n$ converges).

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2056157/show-that-if-sum-n-1-inftya-n2-converges-then-sum-n-1-inftya-n?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112579/converging-series-question-prove-that-if-sum-n-1-infty-a-n2-converge?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Using the following inequallity $(a_n-\frac{1}{n})^2\ge 0$ one has $$ a^2_n+\frac{1}{n^2}\ge 2 a_n \frac{1}{n}$$. Dividing  by 2 , taking sums you have the convergence of the greater sum, so your series converges